# Angularjs: is it possible to use nested dom as component's template?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to use existing dome nodes of component as it's template. transclusion is the closest I what I ended up with, but it still requires additional wrapping elemwe

```
app.component('widgetDom', {
    controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = "I'm data for nested dom elements";
  }
});
```

And then display it as

```
<widget-dom>{{data}}</widget-dom>
```

But it won't work.

With transclusion I would end up with:

```
<widget-dom><div ng-transclude>{{data}}</div></widget-dom>
```

Is there a way to just use nested DOM elements as template for component/directive?

Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/yb9dzkyv/

Comment: You can only use `template` or `templateUrl`. If you want to use parentScope data you can send it with binding.

Comment: Not without a hack. Nested DOM can be retrieved in directive `compile` function and compiled with $compile against current scope. Components aren't supposed to work that way, and if you care about further upgrade to Angular 2+, it will certainly have problems with such approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by components always having an isolated scope from it's parent. If you define your "component" as a directive instead, you can configure the directive to share the scope of the parent, thus making this possible.

Like such:

```
app.directive('widgetDom', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Hello, {{data}}!</div>'
  };
});
```

[Here's a plunker showing it working](https://plnkr.co/edit/xAsZRBdploYk24ByvmBc)